# c++ vector constructors

Tags: c++, vector

I am reading the explanation of the constructors for `vector` at

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd constructor, the parameter `const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()` seems to be always omitted when initializing (see the example below on that webpage), but why is that? What does `const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()` really mean?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's a default argument.

Comment: Like chris says, it's a default parameter. In your link is an explanation: `Allocator object.
The container keeps and uses an internal copy of this allocator.
Member type allocator_type is the internal allocator type used by the container, defined in vector as an alias of its second template parameter (Alloc).
If allocator_type is an instantiation of the default allocator (which has no state), this is not relevant.`